Not receiving answers. What steps can I take?
My previous post: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20553/bounty-on-my-question has been closed with the following feedback:

Asking for responses to questions with a bounty on them is NOT the point of Meta here on Ask Ubuntu. Read the Meta help center for how to use meta.

However, here I am asking an actual question. Only two days left for the bounty on my question How do I share my custom snippets with others in JupyterLab version 4.0 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?. I have made a series of edits based on every comment by muru and I am still not getting an answer for the question. What steps can I take for my question?

Not all questions receive answers.

For clarity, this is the content of that post you made:

Bounty on my question [closed]
Only three days left for the bounty on my question How do I share my custom snippets with others in JupyterLab version 4.0 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?. I have made a series of edits based on every comment by muru and I am still waiting for an answer for the question.

As posted, it is basically only you trying to get attention to your answer by posting on Meta, and that is not what Meta is for.

Now to answer your question here:
There are no additional steps you can take except hope someone will post an answer.
Not all questions receive answers, and there's nothing you can really do within the confines of Ask Ubuntu policies to do to raise any awareness.
Either you get an answer or you don't.  There's no way around this point.  Bounties help gain attention to a post but are ZERO guarantee you'll actually get an answer.
